# Google Closure external dependencies

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

I want to load one single, minified javascript file per page instead of dozens. I'd like to use Closure Compiler to create these so called modules. But I have dependencies like jQuery or Codemirror for example.

**Can I make the Compiler automatically include these for all output, without having to wrap these libraries into Closure specific code to provide a namespace recognized by Closure?**

Comment: Don't you only need to include the Closure Compiler annotations if you're using advanced optimisations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - if you use the `SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS` level of the compiler you can feed all your dependencies into the compiler and it will output a single JS file. `SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS` will work correctly with most code libraries.

```
java -jar compiler.jar -O SIMPLE --js jquery.s --js otherlib.js --js myfile.js
    --js_output_file mycombinedfile.js
```

However, Closure-compiler will need some method of determining the source files if you don't want to list them manually. The compiler can be used with the closure-library dependency management or with Common JS dependency management.

If you don't want to use either of those, you would need a method (like a script) to determine all of the applicable source files and feed those to the compiler **in the correct order**.

Comment: I ended up putting every third party library into a folder, because it turned out, that the Compiler accepts folders too. Easy way to have them compiled, just have to list the directory before anything else.